# Rotor types in Synchronous Reluctance Motor

Tags: motor, electric-machine, synchronous, rotor

I am doing research on Syncrhonous Reluctance Motor (SynRM) and the rotor used in it. I am a bit confused in their rotor types. Now according to Google, the rotor types do consists Salient Poles Rotor but according to Chat GPT, salient pole is not used in Synchronous Reluctance Motor but instead is used in Syncrhonous Motor. I know that SynRM does have axial and radial rotors. Does SynRM also has a salient pole rotor and if yes how good and efficient it is?

Edit: I am trying to design a SynRM but I can't seem to get hold of specs for the axial or radial rotor. If you could guide me to some specs then I would like to draw it on AutoCAD and analyze it on ANSYS Maxwell.

One more thing if I design a rotor in ANSYS Electronics Desktop, will I get to know the dimensions? Like the barrier widht and depth and angle of each barrier?

Comment: Please do not use chatgpt for things like this. Remember that LLMs like chatgpt do not have any concept of "true" or "false"; all they do, all they are *designed* to do, is to take your question and give you something that looks like an answer. Not even something that *is* an answer, just something that convincingly *looks like* one.

Comment: @Hearth I so much agree with you. at one moment the answer is something but when i reload the answer it totally gives another answer and negates it's own answer.

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad As for a LLM "changing it's answer", in a comment in [How do AI developers for LLM fix bugs when the LLM misbehaves, given that they cannot control what the LLM learns from the data?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/450150/how-do-ai-developers-for-llm-fix-bugs-when-the-llm-misbehaves-given-that-they-c/450152#comment990868_450152) the reply was that ``LLMs use random to choose which probabilistically weighted word comes next``. So, even less reason to trust the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reluctance motors *necessarily* have salient-pole rotors, as there would be no angle-varying reluctance (which is the key parameter that makes reluctance motors work in the first place) if the rotor were perfectly cylindrical.

They almost always also have salient stator poles, though this is not an absolute necessity for them to work as it is for the rotor.

Synchronous motors also frequently (maybe even usually) have salient poles, which can improve performance (effectively using it as both a synchronous and a reluctance motor at the same time), but this doesn't mean that reluctance motors don't also have salient poles.

Comment: so Synchronous Reluctance Motors do have salient poles?

Comment: Yes, all reluctance motors do.